# Verify return using Jest

Tags: javascript, typescript, jestjs, testcase

I am quite new to Jest and trying to test this function in which I have stopped the execution based on certain condition.
What would be the best approach to tackle this scenario, here is a snap of my code:

```
function(data: any){
    // Some operation
      if(data.anyProperty === '')
          return;
    // Some more operation
}
```

Please note that I am not returning anything from the function,
As I am not returning anything, for other scenarios, I am cross verifying updated values in the `expect` but unable to understand what should be in `expect` for `return`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Ideally a function should either return a value, update/modify some value or should raise any error.**

For your case where your function is not returning anything, Using **return without a value** will return the value **undefined**, so you can have your `expect` something like this:

```
expect(<your function()>).toBeUndefined();
```

More over in most of the framworks there is an explicit assertions for 'Doesn't throw', so If your function is not doing something special which you can assert then you can have something like this:

```
expect(() =>{}).not.toThrow()
```

It says that your function ran successfully without throwing any concerns.